# Get "NameError: name 'IP' is not defined" error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, scapy

I try to run a python code from online course to create a raw network packet and send to a network by scapy with python 3.4.2 on Debian 9 but I got the error message as show below:

> NameError: name 'IP' is not defined

when I look into the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#for python 3 , must install scapy for python3 first by type command "pip3 install scapy-python3"
import scapy.all

frame = scapy.all.Ether(dst="15:16:89:fa:dd:09") / IP(dst="9.16.5.4") / TCP() / "This is my payload"
```

there is a red line under "IP" and "TCP" method and then It tell that those 2 methods are `Unresolved reference`

I try to change how to import scapy library

```
from

import scapy.all
```

to

```
from scapy.all import *
```

but the problem is not resolved. What do I something wrong?

Comment: Does this behavior persist when you use `from scapy import *`?

Comment: @Clay yes and It give me another error too that is "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'Ether'"

Comment: try from scapy.all import *   and in code  Ether(dst="15:16:89:fa:dd:09")/IP(dst="9.16.5.4") / TCP() / "This is my payload"

Comment: Just to expand on @galaxyan's comment, `scapy.all.Ether` should work with the first import, but you'd also need to use `scapy.all.IP` and `scapy.all.TCP`. On the other hand, if you use the `import *`, then you need to *remove* the `scapy.all` from `Ether`. Read up on how module namespaces work: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=import

Comment: @galaxyan thank you so much. It's work now when I try to run a code via Terminal although in the IDE Tools, it still show a red line under IP() and TCP()

Answer (score 3):

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#for python 3 , must install scapy for python3 first by type command "pip3 install scapy"
import scapy.all.Ether
import scapy.all.IP
import scapy.all.TCP

frame = Ether(dst="15:16:89:fa:dd:09") / IP(dst="9.16.5.4") / TCP() / "This is my payload"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay , this may help you because I did the same mistake.
Make sure your filename is not scapy.py

Answer (score 0):

Since you did

```
import scapy.all
```

You will have to refer all the types with the 'scapy.all' prefix.

```
>>> import scapy.all
>>> frame = scapy.all.Ether(dst="15:16:89:fa:dd:09") / IP(dst="9.16.5.4") / TCP() / "This is my payload"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'IP' is not defined
>>> frame = scapy.all.Ether(dst="15:16:89:fa:dd:09") / scapy.all.IP(dst="9.16.5.4") / scapy.all.TCP() / "This is my payload"
>>>
```

Another way around it is

```
from scapy.all import *
```

But that tends top pollute your namespace.